# Summation of Legendre polynomials $\sum_{l=2}^{\infty} \frac{(2l+1)(l+1)}{K+(l+1)(l+2)(l-1)} P_l\left(\cos(\theta)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to find a closed form for the summation:

$\sum_{l=2}^{\infty} \frac{(2l+1)(l+1)}{K+(l+1)(l+2)(l-1)} P_l\left(\cos(\theta)\right)$

Where $K$ is a positive real number.

I managed to find a closed form when $K=0$ by using the formulas 5.10.4; 5.10.5 and 5.10.6 of the Book "Integrals and Series Vol 2" by Proudnikov.

Indeed, when $K=0$, reducing the above fraction to simpler fractions, and using the fact that:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}P_k\left(x\right)=\ln{(\frac{2}{1-x +\sqrt{2-2x} })}$

and

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1}P_k\left(x\right)=\ln{(1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2-2x} })}$

you can get a closed form for the summation.

Could you give me some hint if it is possible to find a closed form even when the constant $K$ is not zero? and maybe where to start from? Or if it is possible to obtain approximated solutions.

**EDIT: First steps in working out the solution, starting from the answer of Dr. Wolfgang Hinze:**

we start by casting the original fraction into a sum of its complex partial fractions:

$\frac{(2l+1)(l+1)}{K+(l+1)(l+2)(l-1)} = \frac{A}{l-q1}+\frac{B}{l-q2}+\frac{C}{l-q3}$

where $q1$, $q2$, and $q3$ are the three solutions of the equation $K+(l+1)(l+2)(l-1)=0$ and the complex coefficients $A$, $B$, and $C$ are obtained matching the coefficients of the powers of $l$ in the numerator.

Now for each of the fractions $\frac{A}{l-q1}$ it is possible to apply the answer of Dr. Wolfgang Hintze which starts by writing the fraction $\frac{A}{l-q1}= A \int_0^{\infty} \exp{\left(-z (l-q1) \right)}dz $ and then using the generating function, as explained below.

However this integral does not converge for arbitrary values of $q1$; indeed it is necessary that $l > Re(q1)$.

Unfortunately, by choosing $K >0$ in the equation $K+(l+1)(l+2)(l-1)=0$ two solutions always have real part bigger than zero, meaning that the above integral representation of the fraction doesn't apply for all the $l$ in the summation.

Is it possible to use a different integral representation for this fractions?
Is there a workaround for it?

**EDIT2: To successfully complete the bounty I expect the solution as a closed form (even if not pleasant), or if not possible the demonstration why it is not possible**

if you feel like you need more details, I would be glad to provide them, as well as collaborating towards the solution.

Comment: I suggest to write the $l$-th coefficient as an integral (of a function times $x^K$) then exploit the generating function for Legendre polynomials. It is not granted that the final outcome is a "pleasant" function, but that is the same approach one may use to prove the stated (known) identities.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. Do you have any reference on how to proceed? Or maybe could  you elaborate your comment into an answer? I would really appreciate any hint on how to proceed

Comment: They are not pleasant computations to carry on, would you add some context? What is the origin of this peculiar problem?

Comment: This summation comes from a spherical harmonics expansion of an axysimmetric problem on the unit sphere. It describes the deformation of the surface under a point forcing located at the north pole. Indeed I am expecting that the above summation diverges for $\theta=0$ (the north pole) as $P_l(1)=1$ and for large $l$ the summation is proportional to the harmonic series. But I believe it is finite everywhere else. I am looking for an indication on how to proceed, something like a starting kick and a good reference (also an example might work) i can work out unpleasant calculations myself.

Comment: Following the hint of Jack D'Aurizio I find with Mathematica for the much simpler case Sum[P(n,x)/(k+n),{n,0,oo}]  a combination of AppellF1 hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is very interesting, did you simply performed the summation to infinity leaving mathematica to give you the answer or you performed some step before on your own? I am asking all these questions because i am an engineer and I never had courses on how to use generating functions to evaluate summations.

Comment: @SSC Napoli As agreed I have put an extended post in the chat room that you have opened. Have you seen it?

Comment: Hi, I had a look at it. But didn't had time to go into the details. From the quick look I had I still had a couple of questions on the derivation of the result. I will probably reply on the chat today or tomorrow. Would that work for you?

Comment: Please continue the conversation in the chatroom. Just ask your questions there, and I'll try to answer them. We  should do this asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but it shows, for a simplified version of the problem, how a frequenty used approach works.

Consider the simplified problem to calculate the sum

$$s(k,x) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{P_n(x)}{k+n}$$

Where $k>0$ is a real parameter.

The generating function for the Legendre polynomials is

$$g(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2 t x+1}} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } t^n P_n(x)$$

Now writing

$$\frac{1}{k+n}=\int_0^{\infty } \exp (-z (k+n)) \, dz$$

inserting this into the expression for $s$ we get

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } P_n(x) \int_0^{\infty } \exp (-z (k+n)) \, dz$$

Interchanging summation and integration gives

$$\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } P_n(x) \exp (-z (k+n))\right) \, dz$$

Extracting the factor $ \exp (- k z)$ from the sum this can be written as

$$\int_0^{\infty } \exp (- k z) \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \exp (- n z) P_n(x) \, dz$$

Now the sum can be done using the formula for the generating function of the Legendre polynomials (with $t = \exp(- z))$ with the result

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \exp (-n z) P_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2 x e^{-z}+e^{-2 z}+1}}$$

Hence we arrive at this integral representation of $s$:

$$s1(k,x) = \int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-k z}}{\sqrt{-2 e^{-z} x+e^{-2 z}+1}} \, dz$$

Mathematica gives for this integral the closed form expression:

$$s1(k,x) = \frac{1}{k (k+1) (k+2)}\left( (k+1) (k+2) F_1\left(k;-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};k+1;x+i \sqrt{1-x^2},x-i \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)+2 k (k+2) x F_1\left(k+1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+2;x+i \sqrt{1-x^2},x-i \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)-k (k+1) F_1\left(k+2;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};k+3;x+i \sqrt{1-x^2},x-i \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)$$

Here $F_1$ is the Appell1 hypergeometric function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html).

Admittedly, this is not a very "pleasant" expression, but the result for the complete  problem of the OP can be expected to be even uglier, if it has a closed form at all, which I doubt.

**EDIT**

For integer $k$ we get closed form expressions (always for the simplified Problem). The first few are

$$s(0,x) = \log (2)-\log \left(-x+\sqrt{2-2 x}+1\right)$$

Notice that for $k=0$ the n-sum starts at $n=1$.

$$s(1,x) = \log \left(\frac{x-\sqrt{2-2 x}-1}{x-1}\right)$$

$$s(2,x) = \sqrt{2-2 x}+2 x \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2-2 x}+1\right)-1$$

$$s(3,x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\left(6 x^2-2\right) \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2-2 x}+1\right)+3 x \left(\sqrt{2-2 x}-1\right)+\sqrt{2-2 x}\right)$$

$$s(4,x) = \frac{1}{6} \left(6 x \left(5 x^2-3\right) \coth ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2-2 x}+1\right)+5 x \left(3 x \left(\sqrt{2-2 x}-1\right)+\sqrt{2-2 x}\right)-2 \sqrt{2-2 x}+4\right)$$

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, it really helps me a lot in understanding what Jack D'Aurizio was saying and I really appreciate it. However, I miss a step before you arrive to the integral formula, do you set $t=\exp{-z}$ and then carry out the summation? I know i might be asking a lot, but could you write a few more steps (before the integration) so that it could be more clear to me? Do you have any reference book with examples of this technique?

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put in answering my question, and the example really clarifies a lot about the summation as you made the derivation really straightforward. However in your case the fact that you could separate the $e^{-z(k+n)}$ into $e^{-z \, k}*e^{-z \, n}$ made the calculation very easy. But what if I take $\frac{n}{k+n^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{k+n}$? i can write it as $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-z \frac{n^2+k}{n}}$ but then i cannot simply decompose it into two parts, one that contains only $k$ and another containing only $n$. I will obtain $e^{-z \frac{k}{n}}e^{-z n}$

Comment: @user3810266 This case can be done with similar methods: 1) decompose 1/(k+n^2) into (complex) partial fractions. These can be represented via a z-integral as before 2) generate the factor n derivating Exp(-a n) with respect to a 3) now you have this geometric sum:  $\exp ((i k) (-z)) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp (-a n) \exp (n (-z)) P_n(x)$ 4) this gives the sqrt expression of the g.f. 5) take the real part, derive with respect to a and let a ->0 and you get the Integrand of the z-integral.

Comment: @user3810266 It is even better: from the hints of my last comment you can gather how to transform your original L-sum into a sum of z-integrals.

Comment: It is not completely clear to me the point number two, what is $a$? what do you mean by generate the factor $n$? could you put some more details in the form of an answer?

Comment: Do you really need to do all that steps? If you decompose into fractions of the type $\frac{A}{n+i k}+\frac{B}{n-i k}$ i don't see why I cannot apply the steps you showed in your answer, and just factorizing the constants $A$ and $B$. am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: @SSC Napoli Yes, you are right in this case.

Comment: Many thanks as always for your quick answer, i am thinking now at the original problem that i posted. The problem that i am facing is that, after reducing the original fraction into fractions of the kind $\frac{A}{n + k}$ (with $k$ and $A$ complex),  the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} exp \left({-z \left( n + k \right)} \right) dz$; with $k$ now a complex number with negative real part and either positive or negative imaginary part does not converge for all the $n>0$; can i express the fraction with a different integral? is there a workaround?

Comment: Following my comment i modified my question writing some more details than the one I wrote in the comment above, I hope you can find them useful.

Comment: @SSC Napoli  The magic word here is "analytic continuation". Leave the roots as formal parameters, and don't care about possible divergences of the integrals. Carry out the summation, and afterwards insert the true expressions for the roots. If you are lucky, the final expression will be well defined. If not, there's some deeper reason for this singularity. As an example consider the Sum(z^n/(n-3/2),(n,0,inf)). Replace 3/2 by the parameter p, do the integral trick, perform the summation, and in the end let p->-3/2.

Comment: @SSC Napoli I have now done the complete calculation. I have found that your sum can be expressed through the Appell1-function and its derivatives. The remaining problem is now for me to find the time to check the result thoroughly and to write it down here as an answer.

Comment: Is the solution process given by what you posted in your previous comment? that is to say, leaving the roots unexpressed and evaluating the summation? If so I might also start to work out the derivation and we can compare the results...

Comment: @SSC Napoli yes, I did it as described. BTW If you're using Mathematica to perform the steps we could compare our developments directly.

Comment: Yes I do use mathematica, I hope I can find time to perform the calculation and post the results tomorrow.

Comment: @SSCNapoli Very good. I have the mathematica notebook ready. If you give me your email adress I can send it to you, and we can continue the discussion via email. The result is very long and not suitable to be simply presented in this forum. I have found that the case of a double root in the denominator leads to an integral which I (and Mathematica) could not solve. This happens if K = 2/27 (10 +/- 7 Sqrt[7]).

Comment: sure, is there a private way of doing this? (without having it appearing it here)

Comment: I created a chat named "Summation of Legendre Polynomials" you can find it in the available chats. We exchange our results there.

Comment: I was there for some time, but alone ... Next try tomorrow.